# minZoom Prop is not working as expected on antd-img-crop

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have been working with this package and it's pretty cool, but when I added the minZoom prop less than 1 it is not returning the complete image and cut off some of its parts on its own. I have created a sandbox link please have a review by doing some zoom out an image and properly fit in
https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-img-crop-forked-7yl9cg?file=/src/index.js

After uploading this image
[image: coach-image-cid-791-1651835562342-cmwea9 (1)]

I am receiving this, as you can see how some of its part is cutted
[image: 99A18A5F-23F9-434D-85FD-B0CD79E02E8F_4_5005_c]

If I am doing something wrong please do let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

antd-img-crop works perfect, minZoom is working. You have just to define the minZoom according to the size of the picture frame. Your image seems to be not working because it is rectangulare, and then even if you set zoom to 0.5 the rectangle is wide than the square you are using for ratio (1/1)

Comment: I need an image in an aspect ratio of 1x1 and with minZoom all the content it shows in the crop area it should return, and not crop on its own. Is there any possible way with antd-img-crop I can have an image with some specific aspect ratio irrespective of the aspect ratio of an actual image and I can receive a complete image that fits in that crop area?

Comment: You can try to get the image size after it get picked from the user storage and compare its ratio to the 1/1 you want.  Then try to defined the minZoom according to the two. let say you have a 4/3 image et you want a 1/1, you can set min zoom to 0.25 . O.25 because (1 (what you want) /4 (what you have, 4 instead of 3 because 4 is larger))=0.25

Answer (score 0):

try to use props

```
 <ImgCrop
       cropperProps={{ restrictPosition: false }}
   >
```

it was good solution for me